# Validation issue in laravel update function

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5, laravel-6

I'm having a admin dashboard in my laravel application

From the dashboard Admin can edit the user profile contents.

Here is my current usercontroller (only the update function included)

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => ['required', 'alpha','min:2', 'max:255'],
        'last_name' => ['required', 'alpha','min:2', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required','email', 'max:255', 'unique:users,email,'.$id],
        'password' => ['same:confirm-password','regex:/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{12,}$/'],
        'mobile'=>['required', 'regex:/^\+[0-9]?()[0-9](\s|\S)(\d[0-9]{9})$/','numeric','min:9'],
        'username'=>['required', 'string', 'min:4', 'max:10', 'unique:users,username,'.$id],   
        'roles'=>['required'],
        //'user_roles'=>['required'],
    ]);

    $input = $request->all();
    if(!empty($input['password'])){ 
        $input['password'] = Hash::make($input['password']);
    }else{
        $input = array_except($input,array('password'));    
    }

    $user = User::find($id);
    $user->update($input);
    DB::table('model_has_roles')->where('model_id',$id)->delete();

    $user->assignRole($request->input('roles'));

    if($input['roles']=='customer'){
        return redirect()->route('customers.index')
                    ->with('success','Customer has been updated successfully');
    }
    else{
        return redirect()->route('users.index')
                    ->with('success','User has been updated successfully');
    }
}
```

Now my problem is,

When ever admin updates an user without changing the password fields, the password fields get validated and throw me a regex error related to the password...

How can I avoid that issue and validate password field only if they are being changed.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter I have validated the password field with same:confirm-password, so do I need to validate the confirm-password field again?

Comment: but in the default laravel auth used registration, only the password filed is validated right?

Comment: Does it work if you add `nullable` to your `password` rule? I.E.: `'password' => 'nullable|same:...'`. The `password` field should be blank if the Admin doesn't fill it out, and `nullable`, as the first rule, *should* prevent the other rules from being checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current validation rules password field will always be checked with the regex. Adding `nullable` rule in first position of your password validation rules could help you solving the issue.